# Problem about destroying xtemplate used in DataView [after dragging]

Tags: templates, sencha-touch, extjs, dataview

I used **XTemplate** and coded some html to be rendered in a dataview component.

My navigation structure depends on **destroying and construction new panels** so I destroy current panel when user navigates to another panel.

(When using panel which has dataview component) After user taps,holds on screen and drags the dataview panel and then navigates to another panel, panel with dataview is destroyed,new panel is rendered **but html coded xtemplate objects still stays on screen**.

I think this is a **bug** but wanted to know if anyone exprerienced and found a solution.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know someday somebody will have the same problem so I write here my own solution :

I put `Ext.repaint();` after showing up the panel so redraw the new panel and remove xtemplates so get rid of those corrupted screen view.